# How do i cast to a generic type like that: MyType<ConformingX> (ConformingX is a class that conforms to a protocol)

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

how would i achieve this: I want to cast to a generic type with a typeParameter that conforms to a protocol.

I tried the following:

```
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X>
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X> where X: SomeProtocol
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X where X: SomeProtocol>
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X: SomeProtocol>
```

But nothing works.

Here is some example code to get you up and running. Just put it in a Playground:

```
import Foundation

protocol SomeProtocol{}
class X{}

// example class that conforms to the protocol
class ConformingX: SomeProtocol{}

class BaseType{}
class MyType<X>: BaseType where X: SomeProtocol{}

let notCastedMyType: BaseType = MyType<ConformingX>()

// not working
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X>
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X> where X: SomeProtocol
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X where X: SomeProtocol>
let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X: SomeProtocol>
```

Comment: You are using `Value` for two separate things: as a class name (`class Value{}`) and as a type parameter (`class MyType<Value>`). This is legal in Swift but it makes your question much harder to understand. If you edit your question to only use `Value` for one purpose, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I think i am saying that :D. But how would you edit the question?

Comment: I can’t tell you how to edit your question, because I don’t know what result you actually want.

Comment: Suppose you change the declaration of `MyType` to `class MyType<X> where X: SomeProtocol {}`, and you make no other changes. What do you want Swift to deduce as the type of `castedMyType`?

Comment: I just want to get MyType so i can use its functions etc. but i cant cast like that: 'let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution for my complex case. Just add the same generic to the class that is running the code:

```
class ClassThatRunsTheCode<X> where X: SomeProtocol{

    func executingFunc(){
        // working
        let castedMyType = notCastedMyType as? MyType<X>
    }
}
```